# Mapping to wwwroot in ASP.NET 4 - but with MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to make only static files accessible which are in the wwwroot subfolder of my .NET 4.x project, following the accepted answer from [Map to wwwroot in ASP.Net 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33470123/map-to-wwwroot-in-asp-net-4)

This means that the MVC script `Scripts/LoginPage/app.js` will no longer be accessible at all, while `wwwroot/Scripts/LoginPage/app.js` will be accessible through `http://localhost:8080/Scripts/LoginPage/app.js`.

However, the project has MVC pages with Bundles, and I am now trying to configure the bundles correctly. The old bundle config is like this:

```
bundles.Add(
    new ScriptBundle("~/Bundles/Scripts/loginpages/index").Include(
        "~/Scripts/LoginPage/application.js",
        "~/Scripts/LoginPage/index.js"));
```

The MVC page is rendering the bundle like this:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Bundles/Scripts/loginpages/index")
```

- If I just keep everything as is, the page contains the unbundled scripts as follows:

  ```
  <script src="/Scripts/LoginPage/application.js"></script>
  <script src="/Scripts/LoginPage/index.js"></script>
  ```

  but the files themselves are not accessible.
- If I move the scripts but keep the bundle config unchanged, scripts are not included in the HTML at all.
- If I move the scripts into the wwwroot subfolder, and change my bundles to reference the scripts in that subfolder:

  ```
  bundles.Add(
      new ScriptBundle("~/Bundles/Scripts/loginpages/index").Include(
          "~/wwwroot/Scripts/LoginPage/application.js",
          "~/wwwroot/Scripts/LoginPage/index.js"));
  ```

  then in the debug version this yields the following result HTML:

  ```
  <script src="/wwwroot/Scripts/LoginPage/application.js"></script>
  <script src="/wwwroot/Scripts/LoginPage/index.js"></script>
  ```

  but the content of the wwwroot folder (which includes the unbundled scripts) will be available at `/`, not `/wwwroot/`, thus the files are not found.

How can I configure my scripts/bundles correctly?

Comment: Have you verified that `http://localhost:8080/Scripts/LoginPage/app.js` actually works?

Comment: @GSerg I have verified that I can access it if I move the Scripts folder into wwwroot/ manually after the build.

Comment: Then surely `<script src="/Scripts/LoginPage/index.js"></script>` would also work?

Comment: @GSerg As I understand it, the `<script src="/wwwroot/Scripts/LoginPage/index.js"></script>` is generated by MVC (in debug build only) in the line `@Scripts.Render("~/Bundles/Scripts/loginpages/index")` based on the bundle definition's `.Include` line. So I would have to drop the whole bundling stuff and start doing everything manually. Which is the last resort.

Comment: I mean that under your first bullet you have `<script src="/Scripts/LoginPage/application.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/LoginPage/index.js"></script>` that you say do not work. If they don't work, then `http://localhost:8080/Scripts/LoginPage/application.js` wouldn't either.

Comment: Under the first bullet point, the javascript file is in the disk folder `Scripts`, and I have configured the server to only serve from the disk folder `wwwroot`, so to serve from `http://localhost:8080/Scripts`, the file needs to go into `wwwroot/Scripts`, but I cannot get the Bundle mechanism to find it there.