How to use css from seperate file in RazorLight?
I want to separate my css from my cshtml file in RazorLight. How could I do this?
I found no documentation or discussion about this common requirement anywhere except here, but the explanation is abstract and not very informative

There is no documentation on how to create custom tag helpers, the only thing about this topic I found on the internet is the reference I linked, unfortunately, this explanation is not enough for me, would be good if somebody shared a small working example, or just a little bit more details about it

1. Create a Separate CSS File:
First, create a separate CSS file, for example, styles.css.
Place this file in a folder that your application can serve, such as wwwroot/css/ in an ASP.NET Core project.
2. Reference the CSS File in Your cshtml Template:


    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Your HTML content -->
    </body>



3. Serve Static Files (if using ASP.NET Core):
You can do it in your program.cs (or startup.cs)
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    // Other configurations...

    app.UseStaticFiles(); // Enables serving static files
}

4. Generate HTML with RazorLight:
When generating HTML with RazorLight, the template will include the  tag, and the styles will be applied when the HTML is rendered in a browser.
5. Ensure Correct Paths:
If your project is structured differently, ensure that the path to the CSS file in the  tag is correct.

You should use the section directive.
Create a new section in the base view or in another view that calls the view you will use, by passing the name you want to the first parameter with the RenderSection() method.
_Layout.cshtml
<head>
   <link href="/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" /> @* base css *@
   @await RenderSectionAsync("head", required: false)
</head>
<body>
</body>

Then use the css file or in-line css you want in the view with @section directive.
/Views/Custom/Index.cshtml
@section head {
    <link href="/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />       
}


Seeing that you are using ASP.NET MVC, this might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33470123/map-to-wwwroot-in-asp-net-4.
